# CustomTkinter TabView return final values

Tags: python, tkinter, tabview, customtkinter

Using classes as recommended at https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkTabview#cgetattribute_name, I have added an overall *OK* button to be clicked when all widgets on all tabs have been populated.

In the example with only one widget below, the first printed response in *MyTabView* is the initial value of `Something` but I want to know the final response after all changes to all widgets.

```
import customtkinter as ctk

class MyTabView(ctk.CTkTabview):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        self.add("tab 1")
        self.add("tab 2")

        self.Entry = ctk.CTkEntry(master=self.tab('tab 1'), textvariable=ctk.StringVar(value='Something'))
        self.Entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

        global response
        response = self.Entry.get()
        print(response)

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tab_view = MyTabView(master=self)
        self.tab_view.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.OKButton = ctk.CTkButton(self, text='OK', command=lambda: self.fn_okay())
        self.OKButton.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='ew')

    def fn_okay(self):
        response = MyTabView.Entry.get() # Gives a no attribute error
        print(response)

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

How can I get all the final values within the App class when the *OK* button is clicked? My `response = MyTabView.Entry.get()` attempt results in a no attribute error but something is required here or the printed response will remain unchanged.

Another attempt was to watch variables [and call a function to record the latest values] in line with [Tkinter: How can I check if any of the widgets of a specific frame have changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70624062/tkinter-how-can-i-check-if-any-of-the-widgets-of-a-specific-frame-have-changed) but this does not seem to work with ctk.

Comment: `MyTabView` is the name of your class. You want to get the value of the instantiated Entry: `self.tab_view.Entry.get()`

Comment: Thanks @Tranbi, I thought there had to be a simple method! If you redo your comment as an answer then I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tranbi posted a straight forward answer in the comments - use the instantiated Entry: self.tab_view.Entry.get()